# how to package and deploy python flask applications?

Tags: python, virtualenv, mod-wsgi, flask

Built a python web-app using flask frame work and with [blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/) . Used [flask-bone](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone) as template.

The web-app is installed on clients box (linux) and apache mod_wsgi configured to run the flask app (/var/www/flaskapp).

I have a settings screen in the web-app, where the user can upload a new version of the web-app as a encrypted tar file (gpg). The clients boxes are already configured with my public key.

the file upload method in the views.py, uses gpg to decrypt, and untars to web-app folder to over write (/var/www/flaskapp).

Question: do i need to run fab setup every time a new tar file is uploaded ? or is there a way to upgrade the flask app using a packed zip (egg) ?

appreciate your responses..

Comment: That depends - what does `fab setup` do?  Will you be adding new dependencies that might fail to download and install?  Do you want to be able to upgrade your `WSGI` file?

Comment: fab setup (creates a virtualenv and downloads dependencies based on setup.py), dont need to upgrade the wsgi file.